# How to change size of embedded openoffice/libreoffice draw object in ms word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-draw

I am using MS Office 2010 and LibreOffice 4.1.0.4.

I wanted to embed a few draw diagrams in my Word document (copy pasting from LibreOffice Draw into MS Word is not an option for me because I want to be able to change the diagrams later and I don't want to manage several files).

I can't figure out how to make the size of the "embedded area" larger. When I drag the resize knobs, it jumps right back to its original size after releasing.

Also I can't zoom within the embedded draw document.

Any ideas?

[image]